# Laravel Carbon/Date Change Locale Doesn't Work?

Tags: php, laravel

Trying to serve all dates in website as another language.
But It doesn't make any change.

I set 'locale' => 'tr', in config/app.php file.

My AppServiceProvider.php below:

```
 public function boot(\Illuminate\Contracts\View\Factory $factory)
    {
        $factory->composer('*', 'App\Http\Views\Composers\AuthenticatedComposer');
        Carbon::setLocale('tr');
    }
```

And my resource file like:

```
  public function toArray($request)
    {
        Carbon::setLocale('tr');
        $user = Auth::user();
        setlocale(LC_TIME, 'Turkish');
        return [
            "id" => $this->id,
            "customer" => $this->customer,
            "vehicle" => $this->vehicle,
            "basket" => $this->basket,
            "total" => $this->total,
            "discount" => $this->discount,
            "net_total" => $this->total-$this->discount,
            "status" => $this->status,
            "created_at" => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y'),
            "edit_allowed" => $user->power('process', 'edit'),
            "delete_allowed" => $user->power('process', 'delete'),
            "detail_allowed" => $user->power('process', 'detail')
        ];
    }
```

I expected date to be converted Turkish.
But It returns English date like: "Sunday 06 September 2020"

What's wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

I think its supposed to be the language code like this: tr-TR

Unless its because the intl extension is not on the server. In that case try installing that "sudo apt-get install php-intl"

Comment: I change to tr-TR and response didn't change again. php-intl is installed, I've seen it in modules. (As I know, If intl is not installed, it would return empty. but it returns english)

Comment: In that case om not sure :(

Note though, that when you set "Carbon::setLocale('tr');" and later use it in
 "created_at" => Carbon::parse($this->created_at)->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y'),  
It wont be the same instance of carbon. You should add the set locale in the "create_at" line to make sure the setting is on the same instance. Or take the return of "Carbon::setLocale('tr')" so you use an instance of carbon you have set the locale for.  

```"created_at" => Carbon::setLocale('tr')->parse($this->created_at)->formatLocalized('%A %d %B %Y')```

Comment: setLocale returns a bool, so we cannot call parse()